# If we avoid legal advice, why do we have a law tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-blacklist-request

I saw [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/77779/how-and-if-to-ask-to-be-paid-for-overtime-ontario-engineer) and the comment that caught me off guard was this bit:

> Alright I'll move it away, I figured since there was a "law" tag that it was applicable

Why do we have a [law](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) tag? I saw [this question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/whats-the-legal-tag-for) about the [legal](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) which was to be removed. Should the same be done for the [law](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) tag?

On another note, [legal](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) has reappeared, should they both be blacklisted then?

Comment: AFAIK legal advice !== talking about law (with proper disclaimers)

Comment: We can give prima fascia legal advice, and someone in HR can give more detailed advice, but we cannot advise on actual matters of law.  For example, if a poster says that their manager is telling them to falsify data, we can and should advise them that the manager is suborning fraud.  That is information that even a layman understands.

Comment: I feel the wiki tag for [tag:law] needs updating then, it's a bit rubbish compared to [tag:legal]

Comment: @Draken well..... it even gets more complicated.  Someone in HR, while not a lawyer, will through the course of their duties have more than a layman's knowledge of employment law (or SHOULD)....  I know, it's confusing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is asking for legal advice?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/what-is-asking-for-legal-advice)

Comment: Suggested a dupe which covers what legal questions *are* on-topic. The legal tag has the same explanation. Law tag should be removed or rolled into legal imo.

Comment: Have you looked at the questions that are there and determined if the tag made sense?

Comment: may be it's there to find out in advance which questions to avoid and close

Answer (score 8):

Because one is able to converse in discussions and topics regarding law without asking for or giving legal advice

Comment: Then I feel the wiki for the tag needs updating top reflect that: *Questions about the legal aspects of work contract.*

Answer (score 1):

Because talking about law doesn't necessarily mean you are seeking legal "advice". Not to mention if someone is asking a question regarding the legal/law career fields.

Comment: Seems to add no value to the existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

I clicked the [law](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) tag and they fall into three categories.

- 90% are closed as off topic.
- One was massively downvoted.
- Another few were only on topic because answers didn't pertain to law.

Sounds like the tag should be burninated to me. Ideally with a tooltip "Legal advice is off topic" for instance.

As a sidenote I think we need to articulate much, much better when "legal advice" *is* on topic. For instance, advising to seek a lawyer tends to imply you know enough about relevant laws to hint that a lawyer is necessary. Additionally there is such a thing as employment law that many non-lawyers specialize in applying, e.g. HR and union leaders. I've seen stellar answers here that advise on worker rights and those are extremely on topic.