# Tag synonym: [legal] and [law]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request, legal-questions

I noticed that we have tags both for [legal](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) (189 questions) and [law](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) (73 questions). I think the two words are pretty much synonymous, so I would propose having [law](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) redirect to [legal](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal). Unfortunately I don't have the reputation required to add a synonym to [legal](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal).

**Could someone please propose and/or vote for the synonym so that we don't have two redundant tags, since I don't have the reputation in that tag to do it myself?**

Comment: Great idea, I've wondered why we had 2 as well

Comment: TBH, reading those tag descriptions, seems to me that they are different: *law* is for "legal aspects of work contracts" (which, although we don't give legal advice, these could be answered by anyone with some HR experience), and *legal* is about "working within the legal system such as courts"... based on that, seems to me that the intended use is different...

Comment: @DarkCygnus Hm, I had just thought they were poorly worded ways of saying the same thing, but I can see that interpretation too. If that tag really is intended for legal jobs, I would guess that hardly any of them use the tag correctly, to the point that it's probably not worth trying to enforce that definition.

Comment: @DavidK perhaps a merge would be in place here? That can be done, as far as I recall...

Comment: @DarkCygnus Is a merge different than a tag synonym? I thought they were the same thing.

Comment: (sorry, coffee still doesn't kick in)

Comment: Semi-related prior discussion: [Request to burninate \[legal\] and \[law\] tags](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5539/10313) (the top answer argues against burnination). That said, I agree that one of these should probably be merged into and made a synonym of the other. (If there should be a tag about jobs in law-related fields, it should have a much more clear and unambiguous name than either "law" or "legal", which ostensibly refer to questions related to the law/legal issues themselves.)

Comment: And yes, tag synonyms are slightly different from merges – tag synonyms cause new uses of the synonym to be replaced with the main tag, but questions that already have the synonym tag are not retagged/affected. A merge completely replaces the source tag with the destination tag on all questions that have the source tag (whether or not you leave a synonym in place afterwards), and is much harder to undo. But as stated in the [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ on tag synonyms/merges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/335251): "All good tag synonyms should eventually be merged".